# For triangle ABC, find maximum value of $8+\frac{\sin 2A+\sin 2B +\sin 2C}{\sin A +\sin B +\sin C}$

Tags: trigonometry

Considering only the right hand part of the expression:

$$\frac{\sin 2A+\sin 2B+\sin 2C}{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}$$
$$\hspace{-10mm}=\frac{4\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin A+\sin B +\sin C}$$

I tried sing AM GM, but that  obviously didn’t work

$$\frac{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{3}=(\sin A\sin B\sin C)^{\frac 13}$$

How else should I maximise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the area of the triangle $Area=\frac{abc}{4R}=\frac12r(a+b+c)$. Then, per the sine rule

$$\frac{4\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin A+\sin B +\sin C}=\frac{4\frac{abc}{8R^3}}{\frac{a+b+c}{2R}}=\frac{2r}{R}\le 1
$$
where, given the circumradius $R$, the inradius is the largest for equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=4\cos\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2$

we need to maximize $$S=\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2$$

$$2S=\sin\dfrac A2\left(\cos\dfrac{B-C}2-\cos\dfrac{B+C}2\right)$$

As $\dfrac{B+C}2=\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac A2,$

we get $$\sin^2\dfrac A2-\sin\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac{B-C}2+2S=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\sin\dfrac A2$ which is real,

so, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Comment: Why are you maximising $\sin A/2 \sin B/2 \sin C/2$

Comment: @Aditya, please simplify the given ratio